# Solidity default contract attribute/method scopes

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Reading [this](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3344/function-visibility-whats-the-difference-between-private-and-internal-if-any) thread, it's mentioned what the keywords public, private, internal and external represent, but what is the default specifier for methods and/or attribute contracts in solidty?

Answer (score 5):

**Functions:** the default is `public`
**State variables:** the default is `internal`

You can find more here:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html